# Can you call two separate DAOs from the same controller?

Tags: hibernate, entity, controllers

Does Spring allow you to update and save data to two separate Oracle tables in the same controller `update()` method? Or, do you have to use two separate controllers to do this?

I have a controller and need to update and save data to two separate tables in the same controller `update()` method. For example:

```
model = widgetDAO.update(model);

widgetHistoryDAO.save(model2);
```

The first update statement's model is on the form object for the controller.
The second update statement's model, `model2`, is just a history record, so it is not returned to the controller's caller, since the data is not stored on the form object screen.

When I do this, I try creating `model2` via a new statement, at the start of the controller:

```
WidgetHistory model2 = new WidgetHistory();
```

I can call the update and save statement once with no problem, but when I call the update and save statement the second time, the

```
widgetHistoryDAO.save(model2);
```

statement causes a run time error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:......
```

Anyone seen an error like this?

Thanks for any advice on how to most effectively save/update to multiple tables in the same controller that are not in the same form object (i.e. screen variables on the same screen that the user can add, update, query).

Answer (score 0):

I moved the new statement from the start of the controller to the method holding the update and save calls. No run time error occurred. I also did research and was not finding anything prohibiting using the new statement in conjunction with Spring, though one purpose of using Spring is to avoid as much calling new as possible!